# Not getting devicetoken or not called didfailRemotenotification in ios9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am not getting the devicetoken after installing ios9.3, but previously worked well in ios9.2.1.

Here's code (nothing special)

```
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: I am also getting this same problem in 9.3.1, did you found any solution or reason for this?

Comment: Righnow i dont have any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using beta version then this problem can occur. Check the [Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39609); some people have the same complaint with beta version so it can be told `bug` in beta version of iOS.

Comment: I am not using beta version and even i installed ios 9.3.1 and same problem occurs

Comment: try in another version of ios like ios 8 or 7. If it work then problem should be called strange!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, you will get what error is occur.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSlog("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
 }
```

Comment: I already use this method but the control not goes into this method.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I found that it is because `[application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]` returned `FALSE` in the above code. I don't know why it happens since `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` should also available in iOS 9.3.1.

But anyway, I just change the if case to 
`([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)` to check the iOS version and it now works property.

The code now become

```
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)) {
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
     [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                       categories:nil]
     ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```